# Upgrade Classic ASP Javascript include to .net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic, refactoring, server-side-includes

I'm working on an ASP.net 3.5 project that has evolved out of a Classic ASP project.  We have two old Javascript files that are included in a few pages and have never been updated properly.  The Javascript contains ASP.Net server tags and the files are saved with a .js.aspx extension.

The embedded VB.net refers to shared (static) properties in a class and also the ASP.net Session variable.  The class in question isn't imported in the Javascript files, so Visual Studio fails to compile the page.  However, when you load a page that includes these files, it works fine.

What is the correct way to update these files to .Net standards?  Should we avoid having server tags in Javascript files or is there a .Net way to mingle Javascript and server-side code in an includable file?

Thanks.

**Edit to answer question:**

The file is being included with <!-- #include virtual="myFile.js.aspx" --> inside a script tag.  The compiler error is: "Name 'MyClass' is not declared", where MyClass is the class being referenced.

Comment: Do i understand you correctly, you have an aspx page that is serving up javascript, and inside that page you have some asp.net server side tags, you are then adding a reference to this page from within another page using a script tag? but you get a compiler error in the javascript page? - whats the error?

Comment: Yes, basically.  I have edited my question to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fully qualify your class , for example if your class is in the namespace

> YourCompany.YourApp

then in your .js.aspx file you do `YourCompany.YourApp.MyClass`

And make sure you have added reference to the DLL where this resides.

Also note that ASP style includes do not work in ASP.Net.

Comment: Is the #include virtual bit an ASP style include?  What is the ASP.net equivalent?

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer as fully quantifying the class was what I needed to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you need server side data inside the JS functions, I would suggest different way.

For example, suppose you now have such a thing:

```
function Foo() {
  var f = "hello <%=MyClass.LoggedUser%>";
}
```

Change this to be this instead:

```
function Foo() {
  var f = "hello " + _loggedInUser;
}
```

Then in the `Page_Load` event of the page itself add such code:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "logged_user", "var _loggedInUser = '" + MyClass.LoggedUser + "'; ", true);
```

This will send the value just fine, and in my opinion is more correct than having it directly in the JS code.

Comment: @Cos yep, the `<%= %>` is the way of classic ASP so I avoid it as much as possible in `ASP.NET` :)

Comment: I wish I could accept your answer as the correct answer as well as the above answer!  You've helped me realise that as the Javascript is in an aspx page I can use Page_Load to do things to it.  Perhaps it should have been obvious, but I never thought of it that way.  Thank you so much for enlightening me :)

Comment: Cheers @Cos upvote will be enough recognition for me. Glad I could enlighten you! :-)